# jmeter check different response for same request

Tags: json, api, testing, jmeter

I have this kind of request

```
{ 
"ID":"112345"
"SERVICE":"56AA77"
}
```

The API response could be positive or negative with different element.

positive response:

```
{
"RESPONSE":"OK"
"TEXT":"DONE"
}
```

negative response:

```
{
"RESPONSE":"KO"
"DESCRIPTION":"NOT FOUND"
"ERROR_CODE":"100"
}
```

how can I tested with JMeter using only one HTTP Request Sampler and only one CSV file ?

Actually I'm using two csv files:

```
positive:
TEST_ID,TEST_DESC,ID,SERVICE,RESPONSE,TEXT

negative:
TEST_ID,TEST_DESC,ID,SERVICE,RESPONSE,DESCRIPTION,ERROR_CODE
```

is it possible to use only one file ?
like this:

```
TEST_ID,TEST_DESC,ID,SERVICE,RESPONSE,TEXT,DESCRIPTION,ERROR_CODE
```

how Jmeter can handle this?

UPDATE:

I've two JSON Assertion objects
[image: Positive JSON check]

[image: Negative JSON check]

is it possible to create BeanShell groovy to call one of those based on the ResponseCode ?

```
if (prev.getResponseCode().equals("200") == true) { 

checkResponsePositive

}
else
{
checkResponseNegative
}
```

could someone help me with the right syntax?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

   if (vars.get('RESPONSE').equals('OK')) {
       if (!vars.get('TEXT').equals(response.TEXT)) {
           AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
           AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('TEXT field mismatch')
       }

   } else {
       if (!vars.get('DESCRIPTION').equals(response.DESCRIPTION)) {
           AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
           AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('DESCRIPTION field mismatch')

       }
       if (!vars.get('ERROR_CODE').equals(response.ERROR_CODE)) {
           AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
           AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('ERROR_CODE field mismatch')
       }
   }
   ```
3. The above code will have 2 branches:

   - when `RESPONSE` JMeter Variable is `OK` it will validate `TEXT`
   - when `RESPONSE` JMeter Variable is `KO` it will validate `DESCRIPTION` and `ERROR_CODE` from the response against the relevant JMeter Variables.

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. So, I am assuming you have used sample variables and used them in regular extractor or any extractor or may be using coding. Now, if you used it then it can check the sampler response and write whatever values it may find. For positive they may not find anything, so may write "XXX_NOTFOUND" or null depends on the data extraction approach and code.

In the below, I have used dummy sampler for positive request and put all the regular extractor below it.

[image]

Once you check the csv report generated via view result tree, you can see that variables which are found has been reported and others as "xxxxx_NotFound". This "xxxxx_NotFound" is the value I have provided in the regular expression extractor. In short, for a particular request, you can use multiple extractor and write the output in a single csv. If values found then it will write else it will write what you have given in the default.

[image]

Comment: it seems a good solution, but I need to automate the response check....